Why must `git log --pretty` be followed by an equal mark?
Why does:
$ git log --pretty "format:%h %s"
fatal: invalid object name 'format'.

fail but both:
git log --pretty="format:%h %s"
git log --author bob

succeed? Why is the first line wrong? The first just looks like the third one, but it doesn't work.

That’s the inherent ambiguity of command-line options with optional values. --pretty is one, unfortunately:

--pretty[=<format>]
[…] When =<format> part is omitted, it defaults to medium.

git log --pretty "format:%h %s" treats format:%h %s as a non-option argument (the revision range). git log --pretty="format:%h %s" unambiguously gives --pretty a value and has no non-option arguments.
gitcli(7) convention: “stuck form”
According to man gitcli (git version 2.46.1):

When a command-line option takes an argument, use the stuck form. In
other words, write git foo -oArg instead of git foo -o Arg for short
options, and git foo --long-opt=Arg instead of git foo --long-opt Arg for long options. An option that takes optional option-argument
must be written in the stuck form.

